# XSLT using extra for-each or apply-templates using Muenchian method?

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping, apply-templates

I've started learning XSLT and I've used the Muenchian method in an exercise. I've found **2 different ways of getting my expected result**. With the `apply-templates` and with an extra `for-each`.

The key:

```
<xsl:key name="tech" match="technology" use="."/>
```

The first solution using the apply-templates:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//./technology[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('tech', .)[1])]">
    <team>
        <xsl:variable name="selectedTech" select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../person[./technology=$selectedTech]">
    </team>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <member><xsl:value-of select="name"/></member>
</xsl:template>
```

The second solution using an additional for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//./technology[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('tech', .)[1])]">
    <team>
        <xsl:variable name="selectedTech" select="."/>

        <xsl:for-each select="key('tech', .)">
            <member><xsl:value-of select="../name"/></member>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </team>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Input is something like this:

```
<employees>
    <person>
        <name>Bert</name>
        <technology>IBM</technology>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jack</name>
        <technology>Microsoft</technology>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Karel</name>
        <technology>IBM</technology>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Bill</name>
        <technology>Microsoft</technology>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Joris</name>
        <technology>OpenSource</technology>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Piet</name>
        <technology>OpenSource</technology>
    </person>
</employees>
```

Is it better to use a particular solution of these 2? Or which one of these do you recommend and why?

Comment: Please show the input XML and the key definition. And I don't think it is an issue of for-each versus apply-templates, it looks as in one approach you use the `key` function while in the other you don't use it to find the elements in a group.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I've added it. Yes, but both ways seem to work fine, but which way is the best to use and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have defined a key and want to access the items in a group it is certainly more efficient to use `key('key-name', keyValueExpression)` to do that instead of walking an axis and writing a predicate.

So in my view instead of `../../person[./technology=$selectedTech]` (where I wonder whether it does not need to be `../person[./technology=$selectedTech]`) I would certainly use `key('tech', .)` to find the items in a group.

The decision between `apply-templates` or `for-each` is another question as you can use both.

Generally using `apply-templates` and separate templates a stylesheet is better structured and more readable but for quick and short ones for-each might suffice.

For the whole problem I would define the key on `person`

```
<xsl:key name="tech" match="person" use="technology"/>


<xsl:for-each select="//person[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('tech', technology)[1])]">
    <team>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('tech', technology)">
    </team>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <member><xsl:value-of select="name"/></member>
</xsl:template>
```

And of course the first `for-each` could also be eliminated using `apply-templates` and a mode:

```
<xsl:key name="tech" match="person" use="technology"/>


<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//person[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('tech', technology)[1])]" mode="team"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="person" mode="team">
    <team>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('tech', technology)">
    </team>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <member><xsl:value-of select="name"/></member>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I honestly think that a for-each is more readable, but maybe it isn't in more complex stylesheets. Also, very interesting answer, especially the last part. Thanks! Btw, it has to be `../../person` for some reason.